# CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unexpected "}" in "@WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to build a new feature on a symfony project but when running the app I get this error in a pop window in my browser

[image]

When I click "**OK**" to open the profiler I get the bellow:

```
Unexpected "}" in @WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig at line 21 500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax
```

**Stack Trace**

1. in C:\esnet-portal\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Lexer.php at line 259

   ```
       // closing bracket
       elseif (false !== strpos(')]}', $this->code[$this->cursor])) {
           if (empty($this->brackets)) {
               throw new Twig_Error_Syntax(sprintf('Unexpected "%s"', $this->code[$this->cursor]), $this->lineno, $this->filename);
           }
           list($expect, $lineno) = array_pop($this->brackets);
   ```

The logs have this CRITICAL ERROR:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unexpected "}" in "@WebProfiler/Profiler/base.html.twig" at line 21" at C:\esnet-portal\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Lexer.php line 259
```

I am using:
**Symfony version v4.13.3 ** and **PHP 7.2.15**

I think the only thing I did before getting this error was upgrading composer!

When I run this command: `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` I get the below:

PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\esnet-portal\app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\esnet-portal\app\console on line 10

```
Warning: require_once(C:\esnet-portal\app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\esnet-portal\app\console on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\esnet-portal\app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\esnet-portal\app\console on line 10

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\esnet-portal\app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\esnet-portal\app\console on line 10
```

Comment: Clear your cache ('`rm -rf var/cache/*`), try again.

Comment: now I am getting this Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\esnet-portal\app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\esnet-portal\app\console on line 10

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to create **bootstrap.php** via the command below:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

Also, had to re-clone the repo from git and start with a fresh directory structure, after that I ran **composer install** from within the root directory of my app. No need to update composer.